# Complex pattern Matching

Tags: haskell

Is it possible in haskell to match complex patterns?

I mean, I have a Comma Separater Values (CSV) file:

```
name,ID,fieldA,fieldB
```

is it possible to write a function like:

```
getName (n:',':xs) = n
```

where `n` is not a single element but a list?

Comment: You can use [View Patterns](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~drl/pubs/lpj07views/lpj07views-anglohaskell.pdf) to perform "matching" based on the output of another function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write a function to split your line...

```
import Data.List

parts = map tail . groupBy (/=) . (',':)
```

Then you can write your accessor functions easily:

```
getName xs = n where [n,_,_,_] = parts xs
getID   xs = i where [_,i,_,_] = parts xs
...
```

But as always it would be nice to use a data type:

```
data Record = Record {getName :: String   
                     ,getId :: Int
                     ,getFieldA  
                     ,getFieldB :: String
                     } deriving Show 

initRecord xs = Record name (read id) fieldA fieldB where
                [name, id, fieldA, fieldB] = parts xs
```

Of course, if you need error handling, it gets a little bit more difficult...

BTW, there is a Haskell CSV lib out there: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/csv/0.1.1/doc/html/Text-CSV.html

Answer (score 6):

When I was a wee boy back in the 1980s, I implemented a functional language with complex patterns in that style. It amounted to allowing ++ in patterns. The resulting patterns were ambiguous, so matching involved a backtracking search process: the programmer could effectively specify whether to minimize or maximize the length of the prefix matching the pattern left of ++. The language had a form of "pattern guards", so that a candidate match could be tested to see if a subsequent computation succeeded and rejected in the case of failure. The resulting programs were often in-your-face obvious as to their meaning. It was a lot of fun.

These days, when faced with such problems, I reach for `span`, and if that won't cut it, I use parser combinators.

```
span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

> span, applied to a predicate p and a list xs, returns a tuple where first element is longest prefix (possibly empty) of xs of elements that satisfy p and second element is the remainder of the list

So, in particular `span (/= ',')` will split a `String` into whatever is before the first comma (or the whole thing if there is no comma), and the rest (starting with the comma if there is one).

And if that won't cut it, I use parser combinators.

But I always remember how it used to be easy.

Comment: Sounds like you have invented a mechanism like the function patterns in the functional logic programming language Curry years before [this paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/y2k73226883h4l58). The standard example for function patterns is the following definition of last. `last (xs++[x]) = x`

Comment: Perhaps. I also allowed repeated variables with an equality test, so `elem x (_++x:_) = True; elem _ _ = False` for example

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like `splitOn` from `Data.List.Split` and then pattern match on the list elements.

```
> splitOn "," "a,b,c,d"
["a","b","c","d"]
```

It is in the split package.

For something more complex you can use Parsec.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, I'm not sure but I don't think so. You should probably check out something about [regular expressions](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/efficient-file-processing-regular-expressions-and-file-name-matching.html#glob.regex) in Haskell in order to tackle your problem.